# How can I reduce the Java versions I have installed down to 1?

Tags: java, minecraft, software-uninstall

I have used many different methods to install java because I want to get Minecraft working.  I heard that if I uninstall Java it would uninstall LibreOffice, which I do not want to do. I have a install of sun java, so I think what I'll do is delete all my OpenJDK copies, and Excess sun java 7 copies.

All I want is to rid myself of **EVERYTHING JAVA** except for one so I can stop feeling so java cluttered (among other things, no doubt I've got LibreOffice all confused as to who to choose).

Screenshot from my `/usr/lib/jvm` folder:

[image: many Java versions]

Comment: If you do that you'll lose several programs.  LibreOffice is dependent on Java.  So are a few other programs such as Eclipse IDE.  You must ***REALLY*** be certain you want to purge Java first.  Are you *sure* you want to do that?

Comment: Also, Minecraft only works with Sun (Oracle) Java. You cant use openjdk for it.

Comment: @LordofTime I don't plan on keeping it this way forever, obvious, I code in java> I want to purge my system of java, and from there, I can install java again using apt-get. Unless reinstalling breaks libreoffice, and eclipse, I _should_ be ok.

Comment: @LordofTime yes, so I will probably install sun instead of openjdk

Comment: The uninstallation of Java (OpenJDK) with `apt-get` *will* uninstall LibreOffice. I strongly recommend you do not uninstall *all* your Javas before putting one back on (since the libreoffice package, last i checked, has openjdk as a *dependency*).  Not sure why yuo have java 5 on your system, but the folders taht are links dont actually have content (they have the arrows on them), they link to other folders.  I dont know what they link to though.

Comment: @LordOfTime ah. ok. Well lets edit my answer then

Comment: Although this 5+ year old unanswered question has interesting historical value such as @ThomasWard used to be called @ LordOfTime it addresses Ubuntu 12.04 or earlier which are EOL. OP hasn't signed on in 4+ years and is unlikely to respond to new comments. The Java of that time has been updated many times so VTC as `not reproducible`.